# Laravel, homestead VM phpmyadmin installation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm unable to properly configure phpmyadmin in the VM provided by Laravel.

These are some of the questions asked when installing it.

[image: port]

[image: username]

Pass: secret

[image: phpmyadmin username]

I've tried "phpmyadmin", "homestead"...

[image: db for phpmyadmin]

Here's what I get:

[image: error]

I just can't seem to make it work, I've been struggling with this for quite a while now.

Comment: I can give you the answers to those questions:
Port:  3306, 
User:  homestead (or root), 
Password:  secret (for both accounts), 
Database:  I would give it a name like 'phpmyadmin'.  That should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option that I had suggested on another question, a much simpler DM admin program than phpmyadmin that is full featured and is a breeze to install (it is literally just one php file):

Another alternative that I found super simple and that worked right out of the box I set up a new Nginx site from inside the Homestead box using the serve.sh script:

```
serve adminer.app /home/vagrant/Code/adminer/
```

And then in there I dropped the one page successor to phpmyadmin, [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org).  I also renamed it to "index.php" to make it just work.  Then after adding the adminer.app entry to my hosts file I was good to go.

Had not used a web based MySQL interface in years since I just didn't like maintaining phpMyAdmin but this one is sweet.  One file (plus an optional CSS file if you want a nicer theme) and that is all.  Easy to maintain and update.